# MS project server update resources for timesheets

Tags: rest, ms-project

Since some SOAP operations were removed in Project Server 2016,
we are trying to replace the obsolete SOAP Statusing/UpdateStatus API call with the REST API call /Draft/Assignments('assignmentid') in order to assign resources and set the 'actualWork' property. The MSDN documentation says that we can send a MERGE or a PUT request to that URL but it doesn't mention what the request payload should look like.

Can you let me know what the JSON payload for this call should be?

MERGE _api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/Draft/Assignments('assignmentid')

API documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj668054.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace things in < > with appropriate values for your data

1) CheckOut the project

```
POST <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/checkout
```

2) Add enterprise resource to project team

```
POST <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/draft/projectresources/addenterpriseresourcebyid('<enterpriseResourceId>')
```

3) Create the assignment to an existing task

```
POST <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/draft/assignments/add()
{ "parameters":{
    "ResourceId":"<enterpriseResourceId>",
    "TaskId":"<taskId>"
   }
}
```

4) edit 1 or more assignment properties

```
PATCH <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/draft/assignments('<draftAssigmentId>')
{ "ActualWorkTimeSpan":"PT24H" }
```

5a) Publish & check-in:

```
POST <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/draft/publish(true)
```

5b) Or just Check-in (if you don’t want to publish):

```
POST <pwaUrl>/_api/projectserver/projects('<projectId>')/draft/checkin(false)
```